# Login password not required after sleep

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, password, screensaver

I have an issue where my login password isn't being required after my Mac goes to sleep.

In the **System Preferences > Security & Privacy** pane, I have checked the *"Require password ... after sleep or screen saver begins"* box. Every time I quit System Preferences, the box becomes unticked, and then when my laptop goes to sleep no password is required to login.

I have tried:

- Reseting the PRAM multiple times
- I have restored the /Library/Preferences/com.apple.screensaver.plist from a time capsule backup from before the issue began
- I have ran `sudo defaults -currentHost write com.apple.screensaver askForPassword -int 1`
- I have ran `sudo defaults write com.apple.screensaver askForPassword -bool true`
- I have put my laptop to sleep overnight with the password required option unchecked, and then re-checked it after

I have no clue why this is happening. I'm running a 13 inch MBP, MacOS Sierra 10.12.3. If anyone could suggest a fix